# Save the last letter when typing in a textField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have this function in my application:

```
func typingName(textField:UITextField){
    if let typedText = textField.text {
        tempName = typedText
        print(tempName)
    }
}
```

In `viewDidLoad()` I have written this:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(typingName), for: .editingChanged)
```

All works good, but I want to save only the letter typed by the user.

With this function if I write "hello" it prints: 
"h"
"he"
"hel"
"hell"
"hello".

Instead, I want to have this: 
"h"
"e"
"l"
"l"
"o".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get last character which user entered with keyboard.

You can detect it with delegate method of `UITextField` as shown in below code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tfName: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Need to confirm delegate for textField here.
        tfName.delegate = self
    }

    //UITextField Delegate Method
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        //This will print every single character entered by user.
        print(string)
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

*For any Swift String*, You could get the latest letter from a string like this:

```
let myString = "Hello, World"
let lastCharacter = myString.characters.last // d
```

Note that the data type of `lastCharacter` is *Character?* (optional [character](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character)), you might want to do it as optional binding:

```
let myString = "Hello, World"
if let lastCharacter = myString.characters.last {
    print(lastCharacter) // d
}
```

Since you are listening to [editingChanged](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents/1618241-editingchanged) event, all you have to do in your `typingName` function is:

```
func typingName(textField:UITextField){
    if let typedText = textField.text {
        tempName = typedText
        print(tempName)

        if let lastCharacter = tempName.characters.last {
            print(lastCharacter)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly